# NullPointerException при getHeight

Tags: android, java

```
View scrrr = (View) findViewById(R.id.flabs);
float yyy = (float) (scrrr.getHeight() / 0.95);
findViewById(R.id.flad).setPivotY(yyy);
```

Где тут проблема? Как исправить?

Comment: могу предположить, что в контейнере нет эелемента R.id.flabs, но это гадания чистой воды, больше кода :)

Comment: или, как обычно, не помним/не знаем, что сначала setContentView()
и только потом findViewById()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить

```
Toast.makeText(this, "yyy= " + String.valueOf(yyy), Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
```

Увидишь значение своей переменной, если оно не нулевое, то установку "болта" сделай так:

```
View flad  = (View)findViewById(R.id.flad);
flad.setPivotY(yyy);
```

И еще: почему у Вас сначала в разметке flabs, а потом flab? Это разные вьюшки? Если да то какие?

Comment: Да точно, @woesss прав, Вы скорее всего забыли установить лайаут для показа!